# What does this Economist article title “Paris-on-sea” mean?

Tags: titles

I just read [an Economist article](https://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21725349-states-republicans-are-behind-effort-too-california-pushes-plans-reduce)  titled "Paris-on-sea" which discusses the recent extension of California's cap-and-trade Co2 program to 2030.

What does the phrase **Paris-on-sea** mean here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Paris-on-Sea" is a longstanding English nickname for the French beach resort Deauville, which is regarded as possessing a Parisian chic and sophistication.

The editor borrows that familiar nickname as a pre-title for this article to indicate that California, which includes more than half of the US Pacific coastline, is pressing ahead with plans to adhere to the 2015 [Paris Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Agreement) on reductions in emission of 'greenhouse gases', even though President Trump has announced that the US will withdraw from it.

Comment: But here surely Carbon=C.

Comment: @tchrist You think? Could be, but I don't C it--I'd expect something with 'off' rather than 'on' if that were the intent. I think the key is that this is from a British journal.

Comment: Incidentally, British people love naming things Something-on-sea (where relevant)

Comment: My immediate thought was that this was about California being flooded by rising oceans caused by global warming, to the extent that it would literally be _on the sea_. As a pun, it is clearly too vague and unclear to be very efficient—so far, we have three different people reading three different things into it and one not getting it at all…

Comment: Brighton is sometimes called London on sea. What Deauville and Brighton bear in common is that they were early examples of resorts where the urban gentry took the waters. Deauville features strongly in the works of Marcel Proust, whist Brighton was the site chosen by George IV for his [Royal Pavilion](http://brightonmuseums.org.uk/).

Comment: Sorry - George III. Started in 1783.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Isn't it more general than that, names like Something-on-somebodyofwater are common. IIRC, Dr. Doolittle was from the fictional town Puddleby-on-the-Marsh.

Comment: @marcellothearcane, the French like calling things "on sea" too, or "sur mer" in their case. Boulogne-sur-Mer for example.

Comment: @Barmar yes, they do seem to. Something-on-river as well. (Henley-on-Thames, for example)